# Laravel - MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, mariadb

I am trying to find Payouts where user_id equals 1 from the skyrim table along with it's relations.

The code I executed is:

```
$user_payout = Payout::fromTable('skyrim')->where('user_id',1)->with('game','cluster')->first();
        dd($user_payout);
```

It gives me this error:

`SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'where user_id = ? limit 1' at line 1 (SQL: select * where user_id = 1 limit 1)`

Any reason why this doesn't work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to fetch the data first then do the eager loading of relations

```
$model = (new Payout)->setTable('skyrim')->where('user_id', 1)->first();

if($model) {
    $model->load('game','cluster');
}
```

Comment: Haha, second time helping me successfully. Thank you :)